# How to save populated Document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to save a populated document?

I am trying to do:

```
var Group = new Db['Group']();
for (var i=0; i<50; i++)
    Db.Members.push({ User: { _id: "521014731e27b1b008000002"}, pseudo: 'John' });
Group.save();
```

Schemas

```
var GroupSchemaModel = {
    Members: [{
        User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        updated_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
    }]
};
```

I get the error

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "User"',
name: 'CastError',
type: 'ObjectId',
value: { _id: '521014731e27b1b008000002' },
path: 'User' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

Tells mongoose that `User` field will be a collection of references of type `ObjectId` pointing to another collection.

You, on the other hand, are trying to insert an object there:

```
Db.Members.push({ User: { _id: "521014731e27b1b008000002"}, pseudo: 'John' });
```

Mongoose tries to cast it to `ObjectId` and fails. That's apart from the fact that `pseudo` field isn't in the group schema.

Try this instead:

```
Db.Members.push({User: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("521014731e27b1b008000002"), updated_at: whatever});
```

Comment: Ok, but this way is not very convenient in my case, i am working with this array all the server life, so i need to access the users properties from it. Is there really no way to build a populated Doc and save it ?

Comment: you could define the `User` property as nested object instead of making it a ref